# Section tag width height according text?

Tags: css, html, tags

I republish this post agian, because no any suitable answer found. i try with below codes its working but not best width height of section box according to text. I design three css ids 1st is #wbp_row second is #wbp_col and last one is text id name is #threedtext

```
I try these codes with html5 and css3 techniques.
```

My css Code:

```
#wbp_row {
    position:relative;
    display:table;
    border:solid 1px #0F0;
    min-width:auto;
    max-width:960px;
    max-height:auto !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#wbp_col {
    position:relative;
    display:table-row;
    width:320px;
    min-height:auto!important;
    border:1px solid #000;
    float:left;
    margin:0 0 0 0px;
    padding:0;
}
#wbp_row #threedtext {
    font-size:70px;
    max-height:auto !important;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    /*text-shadow: 0px 4px 0px rgba(82,82,82,.80),
             2px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 7, 0.50),
             3px 8px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.40),
             0px 12px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);*/
    color: rgba(141, 198, 63, 1);
    padding:0;
    line-height:normal;
    overflow:auto;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #F00;
}
```

HTML Codes :

```
<section id="wbp_row">
<Section id="wbp_col">
    <p id="threedtext">Web</p>
</Section>
<!--Cols codes end-->
<Section id="wbp_col">
    <p id="threedtext">Brand</p>
</Section>
<!--Cols codes end-->
<Section id="wbp_col">
    <p id="threedtext">Print</p>
</Section>
<!--Cols codes end-->
```

Comment: what is your query dude.. ?

Comment: "I republish this post agian, because no any suitable answer found." — Don't do that. Improve the existing question by editing it and/or earn enough reputation to offer a bounty on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just write below css rules: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/54yP6/)

```
#wbp_row #threedtext { 
  margin:0; 
}
#wbp_col {
  position:relative;
  display:table-row;
  width:320px;
  min-height:auto!important;
  border:1px solid #000;
  clear:both;
  margin:0 0 0 0px;
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: thanks @era.... Your above codes working and remove bugs

Answer (score 0):

Just delete   `width:320px;` at `#wbp_col`

And then

Add `width:auto;` to `#wbp_col`

and then give `margin:0` to `#wbp_row #threedtext`